# How to add Android SDK in IntelliJ? Error that Java SDK is missing, although it exists

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have Java SDK Installed

[image]

But I still get an error that Java SDK is missing when adding Android SDK

[image]

I add root folder in ~/Library/Android/sdk as SDK path

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use Android Studio, which is IntelliJ based?

Comment: I use IntelliJ for flutter development. And I need to set up Android SDK to be able to create APK from inside IntelliJ

Comment: You're better off installing and running both.  There is no active work on the plugin, and you'll end up spending days of time waiting for any 3rd party plugin development on the vanilla IntelliJ.

Comment: Thx, I am in process of doing just that. I will leave the question in case somebody managed to do it.

Comment: Just to clarify - ahve you clicked on "Apply" after adding JDK 1.6? Have you tried to restart IDE?

Comment: Have you set the JDK on your Project as well?  i.e. under Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK?

Comment: Yes, JDK is working properly